# Orthogonal complement of continous functions subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

In vector space $C[0, 1]$ with inner product given by $⟨f,g⟩ = \int_{0}^1 f(x)g(x)dx$

Let $W=\{f∈C[0,1]:f(0) = 0\}$ be the subspace of $C[0,1]$. Now i am asked to find $W^{⊥}$. If i got it right, the only function $g$ satisfying $$\int_{0}^1 f(x)g(x) dx = 0$$ is $g \equiv 0$.
The thing is, I know that in general $V = W ⊕W^{⊥}$ (I have seen proof for finite dimensions only) for every subspace W of V. But this obviously would not stand in case of example given above (any constant function non equal to zero is in $C[0, 1]$ but not in $W ⊕W^{⊥}$). Why is that? Maybe it has got something to do with the fact that $C[0, 1]$ is infinite dimensional?

Comment: My guess is that $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_{\color{red}0}^{\color{red}1}f(x)g(x)\,\mathrm dx$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, my bad, edited the question.

Comment: The equality $V=W\oplus W^\perp$ doesn't necessarily hold in infinite-dimensional inner product spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For infinite dimensional pre-hilbert space, you do not have $V = W \oplus W^\perp$ for every $W$.

For a hyperplane $W$ (which is the case here), either $W$ is closed and its orthogonal is a line ; or $W$ is dense and its orthogonal is zero. If we write $W$ as the kernel of a linear form, then the first case arise if the linear form is continuous and the second if it is not. In OP, $f\mapsto f(0)$ is not continuous for this scalar product, $W$ is dense and $W^\perp = \{0\}$.

To show this directly, let $f \in W^\perp$. Then, for any $g\in C[0,1]$ such that $g(0) = 0$, we have $\int_0^1 f(x)g(x) \text dx0$.

If $f\neq 0$, then there is a non-empty interval $[a,b]\subset (0,1)$ such that $f$ has constant sign on $[a,b]$. Then, let $g$ be a continuous bump function, positive on $(a,b)$ and zero outside of it. We have $g(0) = 0$ and $\int_0^1 f(x) g(x) \text dx \neq 0$, which is a contradiction. Therefore $f= 0$.